# Is a High R squared a Sufficient condition for a spurious regression?

Tags: time-series, cointegration, spurious-correlation

I know that a necessary condition for spurious regression is a R squared approaching 1.  However, is a R squared approaching unity a sufficient condition?  Said another way, if two non-stationary variables are found to be cointegrated, should we still expect a R squared approaching 1 when an OLS in levels is estimated with these variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**.

For example, suppose $Y$ is a random variable caused by $x$ such that $Y = 0$ when $x = 0$ and $Y = 1$ when $x = 1$. If you choose $x$ to equal independent draws from a standard normal distribution, then $Y$ regressed on the values of $x$ will yield $R^2 = 1$. But this regression isn't spurious. Just the opposite: the choice of $x$ completely determines $Y$.

By the way, $R^2$ near 1 isn't a necessary condition of spurious regression, either. It's just that if the association between two causally unrelated things is present but small, it seems much less worth talking about than if it was a large association.

Comment: Note how the OP says correctly that "a necessary condition for spurious regression is a R squared *approaching* 1" while the second paragraph of your post addresses $R^2$ "[being] *near* 1", which is not the same.

Comment: @RichardHardy Then what does "approaching" mean? Clearly we're not talking about convergence of sequences here.

Comment: It is the regular asymptotics w.r.t. the sample size, I presume, and convergence of distributions of random variables.

Comment: @RichardHardy So you mean the sample $R^2$ converging to 1 as the sample size goes to infinity, that is, the population $R^2$ being 1? I don't see how that's necessary for a spurious regression, either.

Comment: What I meant is the limiting distribution of $R^2$ in spurious regressions, which should be easy to google. I did not intend anything much, just to point out the discrepancy (in this case you addressing something else than the OP actually said). But I am not up to a big discussion, it was just a small "heads up".